# How to add new Element/Palette Component directly in GMF .gmfgen file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I have created a entire model and then got the diagram generated code. Now I realized that I need to add more components in Palette.
But I have already carried out lot of modifications in the already generated Code. 
So if I repeat all the steps, mostly I am gonna loose all my changes. So is there any way to add new components or introduce new element inside Palette without developing from initial cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean exactly? Is it that you're afraid of losing modifications you did to the generated source code? If that's the case you can prevent a function from being generated adding the `@generated NOT` tag.

```
/**
 * @generated NOT
 */
void foo() {...}
```

Comment: To be more specific, anything without the `@generated` tag will be left untouched during regeneration, but I think that way makes it clearer that an originally generated method has been modified afterwards.